# Javascript causing stack overflow at line xx

Tags: javascript, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow in IE with JQuery (at line 12/1076)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768855/stack-overflow-in-ie-with-jquery-at-line-12-1076)

My users (using IE) are reporting the following error:

Stack Overflow error on line 43.

Within my page, I have the following block of javascript to initialize google maps. Here's the complete code:

```
 var map;

    function initializeMap() {

        var locations = [];
        var baseLat = 39.828175;
        var baseLng = -98.5795;

        @if (Model.Clubs.Any())
        {
            @:baseLat = @Model.Clubs.FirstOrDefault().latitude;
            @:baseLng = @Model.Clubs.FirstOrDefault().longitude;
        }

        @foreach (var club in Model.Clubs)
        {
            var content = string.Format("<span style='font-weight:bold; font-size: small;text-align:left;'>{0}<br/>{1}, {2}</span>", club.name, club.city, club.state);
            var link = string.Format("<span style='text-align:left;'><a href='/Search/Details?state={0}&cbsa={1}&clubid={2}' class='moreDescription'>Details</a></span>", club.state, club.cbsa_code, club.id);
            @:locations.push(["@Html.Raw(content)", @club.latitude, @club.longitude, 4, "@Html.Raw(link)"]);

        }

        map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(baseLat, baseLng),
            mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
                position: new window.google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
            });

            window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0] + '<br/>' + locations[i][4]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                };
            })(marker, i));
        }

    }
```

This is line 43: `position: new window.google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2])`

ReSharper is also saying "Declaration hides variable marker from outer scope" and "Declaration hides variable i from outer scope"

Any thoughts on what's causing the overflow?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, can you add additional code?  for example: the code surrounding the given code?

Comment: can you upload a link to the website?

Comment: I can't. It's an internal site.

Comment: It was this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768855/stack-overflow-in-ie-with-jquery-at-line-12-1076?rq=1 and not related to google maps.